# Changing Jackson active view for a property

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson, I'd like to be able to change the active view when serializing a property.

So, if my application uses 3 views, A, B & C, I might want property p for type T to always serialize using view A, regardless if the active view `Class` is `null`, `A.class`, `B.class`, or `C.class`.

I haven't found any way to do this that is built-in to Jackson, so I plan to make my own classes that do this.

Before I possibly reinvent the wheel, is this possible with normal Jackson annotations and/or classes?

If not, I plan to do something like the following (NB: to simplify this question, I've omitted a lot of config options & performance optimizations that aren't necessary for core functionality, but that I'll add once the core works; I've also occasionally omitted visibility modifiers & the like for concision):

1. Make the following annotation that indicates that, for the annotated field or method, the view should be switched from the active view to `value`:

   ```
   @Target({FIELD, METHOD})
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   public @interface JsonApplyView {

       Class<?> value();
   }
   ```
2. If `@JsonApplyView` is applied to a property, somehow change the value of `_serializationView`, `getSerializationView()` & `getActiveView()` in `SerializerProvider` from the original active view to the `value` from `@JsonApplyView` (let's call `JsonApplyView.value` the `appliedView`).

   If there is some better / more correct way to change the active view, please let me know.

   If this is the correct approach, since `_serializationView` is final, and since both getters just return `_serializationView`, I must make a `BeanSerializerModifier` whose `modifySerializer()` wraps its argument serializer with a `ContextualSerializer` with:

   ```
   JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider sp, BeanProperty bp) {
       JsonApplyView apply = bp.getAnnotation(JsonApplyView.class);
       return
           apply == null ||
           apply.value().equals(sp.getActiveView()))
               ? this
               : new ViewApplyingSerializer(this, apply.value())
       ;
   }
   ```

   `ViewApplyingSerializer` would save the following properties in its constructor:

   ```
   final JsonSerializer<?> delegate;
   final Class<?>          appliedView;
   ```

   `ViewApplyingSerializer.serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider p)` would do one of the following:

   1. copy `p`:

      ```
      delegate.serialize(o, g, copy(p, appliedView));
      ```

      where `SerializerProvider copy(SerializerProvider p, Class<?> appliedView)` returns a copy of `p` whose `_serializationView = appliedView`
   2. wrap `p`:

      ```
      delegate.serialize(o, g, wrap(p, appliedView));
      ```

      where `SerializerProvider wrap(SerializerProvider p, Class<?> appliedView)` returns a wrapper around `p` whose `_serializationView`, `getSerializationView()` & `getActiveView()` all return `appliedView`
   3. use a whole new `ObjectWriter`

      ```
      ow.writeValue(g, o);
      ```

      where `ow` is somehow obtained

I imagine that copying the `SerializerProvider` would be best, but the only ways that I've found to copy a `SerializerProvider` and change its active view require passing in a `SerializerFactory`, and the only ways that I've found to get a `SerializerFactory` are to either construct a new one, or to get one from an `ObjectMapper`.  I'd prefer to use the `_serializerFactory` from the current `SerializerProvider` to mimic it as closely as possible, but that field is protected, and I haven't found any getters for it.  What is the easiest way to copy or wrap a `SerializerProvider` to make it have a different view `Class`?

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked a long time ago but I was also looking for doing something similar. I think it would be great if Jackson could support this by itself since it seems to me like a very frequent case.

For example, let say you have a hierarchy of views, where the DetailView (high details) inherits from the SummaryView (low details), and two objects with a child-parent relationship. When serializing the child object with an active DetailView, you might want to add a summary of its parent and not necessarily all its details... then you need to switch from a DetailedView to a SummaryView.

Anyway, no need to explain again the obvious you already know, what I finally did is to modify the BeanSerializer since its only while serializing beans that the JsonView annotation takes place.

```
@Override
public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
    return new JsonViewOverrideSerializer(serializer);
}
```

The `JsonViewOverrideSerializer` keeps a reference of the original bean serializer. What is really important happens in the contextualization: if a property is not annotated with `@ApplyJsonView`, then it return the original bean serializer directly. Otherwise, it wraps the bean serializer after contextualizing it. Something like this:

```
@Override
public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    JsonSerializer<?> serializer = this.beanSerializer;

    if (serializer instanceof ContextualSerializer) {
        serializer = ((ContextualSerializer) serializer).createContextual(prov, property);
    }

    if (property != null) {
        ApplyJsonView applyJsonView = property.getAnnotation(ApplyJsonView.class);

        if (applyJsonView != null) {
            Class<?> jsonView = applyJsonView.value();                
            serializer = new JsonViewOverrideSerializer(serializer, jsonView);
        }
    }

    return serializer;
}
```

Finally, here come's the tricky part where you want to override the `SerializerProvider` object. I did not found any elegant way of doing it neither, so here's what I end up creating a new instance of `SerializerProvider' by retrieving the`SerializerFactory`from the`JsonGenerator`codec, the`ObjectMapper` (me too I would have prefer to retrieve it from the provider being overridden instead but well... too bad I can't a way to have access to it).

```
public SerializerProvider overrideProvider(Class<?> overrideView, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) {
       return ((DefaultSerializerProvider) provider).createInstance(provider.getConfig().withView(overrideView), ((ObjectMapper) gen.getCodec()).getSerializerFactory(););
    });
}
```

(note: to avoid recreating a provider with a same active view, I keep a map of all overridden providers in the provider's attributes).

Finally, I have my serializer look up for its effective provider before serializing the object:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
   SerializerProvider effectiveProvider = provider;

    if (provider.getActiveView() != null && overrideView != provider.getActiveView()) {                              
        effectiveProvider = overrideProvider(overrideView, gen, provider);
    }

    beanSerializer.serialize(value, gen, effectiveProvider);
}
```